# systemd does not reload updated Application code

Tags: node.js, systemd

recently I faced this weird problem with systemd, I have a nodejs app and I run using systemd, well everything works, until I do make any changes to my application code and restart my systemd service, But my newly made changes doesn't reflect in execution(unless I restart my machine).

The other thing I observed, if I use very small application test code then it works as intended, I my assumption is my application code size might be causing this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

```
[Unit]
Description=sandbox
Documentation=https://example.com
PartOf=appbase.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/vx.x.x/bin/node /home/user/repo/Server/SandboxServer.js
Restart=always
Slice=limits.slice
RestartSec=10                       # Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
StandardOutput=syslog               # Output to syslog
StandardError=syslog                # Output to syslog
SyslogIdentifier=sandbox

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is elsewhere. When a `restart` is issued, `systemd` will issue a `TERM` signal to the app and then a `KILL` signal if the `TERM` signal doesn't work, finally the unit will start back up.

Have you confirmed the app is actually stopping and starting?

You could add a signal handler to the TERM or KILL signals to check.